# How to calculate sizes for AVPicture.data[x] pointers (YUV420p) when using libffmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264

I'm trying to get Y,U,V values separately in order to pass them to openGL and map to a texture. I know these values can be found in AVPicture.data[0] (Y)  and AVPicture.data[1] (U)  and AVPicture.data[2] (V)

```
avcodec_decode_video2(ctx, frame, &frameFinished, packet_data->packet);
AVPicture _avPicture;
picSize = avpicture_get_size(ctx->pix_fmt, ctx->width, ctx->height);
avpicture_alloc(&_avPicture, ctx->pix_fmt,ctx->width, ctx->height );
avpicture_fill(&_avPicture, packet_data->packet, ctx->pix_fmt,ctx->width,ctx->height);
```

^^ That's working fine.
The issue I run into is passing the Y,U,V values back to Java via JNI. I have to know the size of the data the AVPicture.data[x] pointers point to. I've tried AVPicture.linesize to no avail, as well as:

```
           for (y = 0; y < ctx->height; y++){
                for (x = 0; x < ctx->width; x++){
                    yDataSize++;
                }
            }
            /* Cb and Cr */
            for (y = 0; y < ctx->height / 2; y++) {
                for (x = 0; x < ctx->width / 2; x++) {
                    uDataSize++;
                    vDataSize++;
                }
            }
```

I'm really stuck, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer size is the linesize times the height (linesize is bytes per row, multiply by number of rows to get total). So `_avPicture.linesize[x] * ctx->height`. Calculate on the C++ side, pass value back to Java.

Comment: I really appreciate the speedy response. Wish I could upvote more than once.